# Why curl command stops downloading file immediately?

Tags: linux, curl, tftp

I set up a TFTP server in Windows and then in a embedded Linux, I ran the command

```
curl tftp://192.168.10.2:69/xxx-fng-in
stall.sh|sh
```

but it stops immediately.

Any suggestion?

Comment: if you don't pipe it into `sh` does it still fail to download?

Comment: Also what version of curl do you have?  From what I'm reading tftp traditionally has a file size limit of 32MB.  Apparently newer versions of `curl`/`tftp` server software are able to bypass this but depending on the tools you are using this may be your issue.  EDIT: Actually I doubt your shell script is > 32MB but still something to be aware of.

Comment: errr... is there really a line break (that you entered) in the middle of the line? Or is that just a copy/paste or line wrap artifact?